# What do string.upper() and string.lower() do?

Tags: python, string

I've been reading and learning Python and I don't understand the following two commands. What do these two commands do And where is the use of them?

string.upper()

string.lower()

I want to learn python conceptually. I don't understand this two commands.

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?  Did you test them and observe their result, and compare that with your understanding of the documentation?  Is there something specific about the documentation or observed result which isn't clear?  Please specify.

Comment: Have you tried running the code?

Comment: I will try code again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert message to uppercase

```
message = 'python is fun'
message.upper()
#output: 'PYTHON IS FUN'
```

convert message to lowercase

```
message = 'PYTHON IS FUN'
message.lower()
#output: 'python is fun'
```